# Stream unsigned long long from C++ server to C# client

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, stream, streaming

I believe readers won't need more code, but if you need to see more code please let me know.

I need to stream bytes from a C++ server to a C# client. I am able to write and read most variables, except when I come to an `unsigned long long` that needs to be sent.

Since there is no unsigned long long in C#, I tried to read the bytes as two integers (4 bytes at a time), but it is not working: The stream still has bytes-to-read even when I consume 8 bytes. See the commented part? If I un-comment them, and execute, they get populated with junk data, this means there were more than 8 bytes in the stream ..

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong? The C++ library is pretty contained and I did not touch it, and it works with most variables (and other applications) except now and in my case. How to send/read/store an unsigned long long between C++ and C#?

Suggestion: Maybe convert the unsigned long long to two ints first, then send the two?

C++:

```
stmOstream& MyClass :: SendToClient( stmOstream& aStream ) const
{
   unsigned long long DoomedVariable;
   aStream << DoomedVariable;

   return aStream;
}
```

C#:

```
NetworkStream myStream;
mSocket = new TcpClient();
await mSocket.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 11111);
myStream= mSocket.GetStream();

private async Task ReadBytes( byte[] InBuffer, int SizeNeeded)
{
    int ReadyBytes = await myStream.ReadAsync( readBuffer, 0, SizeNeeded);

    while ( ReadyBytes != SizeNeeded)
    {
        lBytesReady += await myStream.ReadAsync( InBuffer, ReadyBytes , SizeNeeded- ReadyBytes );
    }
}

private async Task<int> ReadReply( )
{
    byte[] lReadBuffer = new byte[ 2048 ];
    await ReadBytes( lReadBuffer, 4 );
    int FirstHalf = BitConverter.ToInt32( lReadBuffer, 0 );

    await ReadBytes( lReadBuffer, 4 );
    int SecondHalf = BitConverter.ToInt32( lReadBuffer, 0 );

    //await ReadBytes( lReadBuffer, 4 );
    //int JunkData = BitConverter.ToInt32( lReadBuffer, 0 );

    //await ReadBytes( lReadBuffer, 4 );
    //JunkData = BitConverter.ToInt32( lReadBuffer, 0 );

    //await ReadBytes( lReadBuffer, 4 );
    //JunkData = BitConverter.ToInt32( lReadBuffer, 0 );

    //await ReadBytes( lReadBuffer, 4 );
    //JunkData = BitConverter.ToInt32( lReadBuffer, 0 );
}
```

Comment: Maybe convert the long long to two ints first, then send the two? How to convert a long long to two ints?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are going through the trouble of splitting the `unsigned long long` into to ints, instead of just reading it as a `ulong` (which is just the int64 you are looking for) on the C# side?

Comment: @Milster I tried that, but I do not get the same value I send from the server. I think because ulong is 4 bytes, but unsigned long long is 8 bytes

Comment: That's weird. `ulong` is a 64-bit variable (8 bytes), just like `unsigned long long` in C++. However, `unsigned long long` can be bigger than that, depending on the platform the code is compiled on, though quite rarely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a 64 bit long long to two ints:

```
unsigned int firstHalf = DoomedVariable & 0xFFFFFFFF; //first four bytes
unsigned int secondHalf = (DoomedVariable >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFF; //last four bytes
```

In c++ a long long is "at least" 64 bits, so it might be worth seeing how big it is on your platform with

```
printf("%d", sizeof(unsigned long long));
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. When you say `first half`, do you mean the left-most 32 bits?

Comment: Also, can you show how to get the two integers back together to make one `ulong` on the C# side?

Comment: When I say first half I mean the least significant bits, so the right half. On the client side you can just splice your two variables back together like `(ulong)(((ulong)SecondHalf << 32) | FirstHalf)` (You should be able to just use the code you have for getting the two halves) You might have to reverse the byte order depending on how the data is passed to the server (`(ulong)(((ulong)FirstHalf<< 32) | SecondHalf)`)

Comment: I hope that helps :P

Comment: Could you provide info on how to stick this back together c sharp side so I can read the whole number. (Use-case for me in unix time parsing.